# How to update an object and set the state with new object values using React or React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to update an object which is stored in my useState hook 'items'. Code block 1 does not work however code block 2 does. The only thing I did was put my items in a new variable. Can someone explain why code block 1 does not work however code block 2 does work.

Does NOT work

```
const Users = () => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState('');

  const folder = {
    id: itemId,
    title: text,
    location: itemLocation,
  };

  // get object index
  const objIndex = items.findIndex(obj => obj.location === itemLocation);

  // update object
  items[objIndex] = folder;

  // set state with update
  setItems([...items]);
};
```

Below works

```
const Users = () => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState('');

  const folder = {
    id: itemId,
    title: text,
    location: itemLocation,
  };

  // put state into variable
  const myItems = [...items]
  // get object index
  const objIndex = items.findIndex(obj => obj.location === itemLocation);

  // update object
  myItems[objIndex] = folder;

  // set state with update
  setItems(myItems);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
items[objIndex] = folder;
```

You should never update state directly like this. React assumes you always use the "set" functions to update your state, and will not know when to re-render your components if you modify state directly.

https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly

Comment: So would the correct way to do this be to create a copy of the state then make the change and then set the state with the new copy

Comment: What you did there seems reasonable. 
My only concern is why there's a setItems not in a callback or an effect, but I'm assuming you haven't finished the component yet.

Answer (score 0):

```js
  // update object
  items[objIndex] = folder;
```

I believe this is the problem. I actually never tried to change the state itself (I've always assumed it's read-only).

I will test this further later to be sure. But usually you don't edit the state directly (the state means the `items` variable). Either you 1) create an `items1` such as `items1 = { ...items }` and then `setItems(items1[objIndex] = folder)` or you follow your approach in the second code snippet.